# Emacs org-display-inline-images

Tags: emacs, org-mode

*How can I display inline images in emacs org mode?*

I have `[[file:~/myimage.png]]`, which, when clicked, opens the image in a new buffer. 
But how to do it in the same buffer?

**Note:** <kbd>C c C x C v</kbd> is undefined, so I couldn't activate the inline images, but how do I solve this problem?

Comment: This seems to be implemented by default in the latest org-mode (using C-c C-x C-v)

Comment: @stefan is correct, the keybinding for toggle image is actually `C-c C-x C-v` .

Comment: And the command is `M-x org-toggle-inline-images`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This works for me:

```
(defun do-org-show-all-inline-images ()
  (interactive)
  (org-display-inline-images t t))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-x C v")
                'do-org-show-all-inline-images)
```

And here's how I found how to do it:

1. <kbd>M-x apropos RET</kbd> `org.*image.*`.
2. <kbd>F1 f</kbd> `org-display-inline-images`.
3. make a test.org with a link to picture.
4. <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(org-display-inline-images t t)`.
5. wrap it in a `defun`/`global-set-key`.

Comment: No luck so far. And I suppose you meant "kbd "C-c C-x C-v", but even then "C-c C-x C-v" does not display the images inline. It only outputs the message Symbol's function defintion is void: org-display-inline-images. I suppose there is something else that has to be activated.

Comment: It works for me with
1. `emacs -q test.org`.
2. <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(org-display-inline-images t t)`

The emacs is 24.3 on ubuntu.

Comment: If the code in abo-abo's comment doesn't work for you then your emacs might not support images.

Comment: My emacs do support images. So far, I can show inline images with:

Comment: (iimage-mode)
(add-to-list 'iimage-mode-image-regex-alist
(cons (concat "\\[\\[file:\\(~?" iimage-mode-image-filename-regex "\\)\\]") 1))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook '(lambda () (org-turn-on-iimage-in-org)))
(defun org-turn-on-iimage-in-org ()
"display images in your org file"
(interactive)
(turn-on-iimage-mode)
(set-face-underline-p 'org-link nil))
(defun org-toggle-iimage-in-org ()
"display images in your org file"
(interactive)
(if (face-underline-p 'org-link)
(set-face-underline-p 'org-link nil)
(set-face-underline-p 'org-link t))
(call-interactively 'iimage-mode))

Comment: OK. The above problems of mine (and corresponding solution) were with emacs 23. I updated to the 24. version and abo-abo solution is working now.

Comment: But I still have problems with : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637685/configuring-emacs-for-showing-fixed-width-inline-images

Comment: why can't this be a button somewhere in the options menu? I couldn't do it after following instructions. Showing inline images would be so nice along with the outline capability without requiring a superhuman understanding of emacs or orgmode

Comment: `org-redisplay-inline-images` does not show image in terminal emacs is it a normal behavior?

Answer (score 78):

you need not define a custom function like @abo-abo , org-mode has provide such functions :

```
M-x 

- org-redisplay-inline-images
- org-display-inline-images     
- org-toggle-inline-images
- org-remove-inline-images  

M-x org-toggle-inline-images is quite enough for me , which toggle display/hiden inline images
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! By the way, do you know how to resize the inline image when it is too huge to be displayed inside the window?

Comment: Agree with @Xinyang . This should the accepted answer.

Comment: To display them by default, I added this to my .emacs `(setq org-display-inline-images t)
(setq org-redisplay-inline-images t)
(setq org-startup-with-inline-images "inlineimages")`

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I found online somewhere that proved very useful for me (to get org-mode to re-display images when I edited and re-eveluated a graphviz src block, for example), was to evaluate the following (or put it in your init file):

```
(add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook 'org-redisplay-inline-images)
```

I then find myself able to run <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> from anywhere in the source block, and the code is re-executed, with the resulting image automatically displayed.  This combined with either:

```
(setq org-display-inline-images t)
```

or, within a particular buffer:

```
#+STARTUP: inlineimages
```

... should allow you to just always see your images within org-mode, including upon re-computation of an image generated as a result of executing a code block.